# Ruby/Rails: How to periodically update a div using Ajax or any other method

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
I have a show.html.erb where one div (div id="mydiv") needs to be refreshed every few seconds by pulling data from server. I am using AJAX with set interval to get the latest data from backend. But how do I reflect the new values in this div?     

 The following is my **show.html.erb**

   

    <section >
        <ul>
        <span>Test1: </span><span><%= @rec.test1  %></span>         
            <script>        
               $(document).ready(function() {                  
                 setInterval(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                     url: '/my_url',
                     method: 'GET',
                     success: function(data) {
                       //*****NEED TO CORRECT THIS
                        //update "mydiv" with latest values fetched from the server
                        
    //I expected this one to empty the values of the DIV but it did not do that
                        $('#mydiv').val("");  
    // I expected this to change the DIV values to the latest values received from the server but that didn't happen
                        $('#mydiv').val(data);                         
                    }                                             
                   });
                 }, 5000);
               });
            </script>                        
            <div id="mydiv">
                <% if @results && @results.any? %>           
                    <li>                        
                      <% @results.each do |res|%>                
                       <span>Field1: </span><span><%= res["field1"]  %></span>                          
                      <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %> 
            </div>
        </ul>
    </section>   

  **MyController.rb methods**

   

         def show
                @rec
                @result
            end
           
         def my_url   
          result_query = user.mydata
          @results = [] 
          result_query.each do |result|      
            res = Hash.new
            res["field1"] = result["field1"]
            @results << res
            end
          end
         respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json:  @results}      
         end       
        end
```

On successful return of the ajax call, I need to update just the  and not the Test1, Test 2 fields. What should I write in the "success" function so that my div gets updated.

******************ANSWER**************

---

```
 I finally used partials to make this work.
    My controller returned following->

    respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render :partial => "mydiv_results" }  
        end  

My show.html.erb is as follows -->

<script>        
           $(document).ready(function() {                  
             setInterval(function () {
               $.ajax({
                     url: 'myurl',
                     method: 'GET',
                     dataType: 'html',                     
                     success: function(result) {
                        $('#mydiv').html(result);                
                      }                       
                   }); 
             }, 60000);
           });
        </script>
<div id="mydiv">                   
            <%= render partial: 'mydiv_results' %>
 </div>
```

And I created a partial under view as follows-->
_mydiv_results.html.erb

```
<% if @results && @results.any? %>           
                    <li>                        
                      <% @results.each do |res|%>                
                       <span>Field1: </span><span><%= res["field1"]  %></span>
                       
                      <% end %>
                    </li>
                <% end %>
```

the partial gets loaded everytime ajax returns success and hence I am able to make the periodic call and display the result accordingly.

Thanks a lot for all the help guys!

Comment: The question is not clear. What part of do you want to update? The list in the #mydiv? Also what is your data supposed to return?

Comment: @FatimahSanni I updated the question and the code. I want to update #mydiv with the latest values fetched from the server

Comment: Divs don't have any value. That's why `.val()` method has no effect. Use `.html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       $.ajax({
             url: '/my_url',
             method: 'GET',
             success: function(data) {
               $('li', '#mydiv').html(                
               '<span>Field1: </span><span>'+"<%= data.field1  %>"+'</span>'
               '<span>Field2: </span><span>'+"<%= data.field2  %>"+'</span>'

                );                                                                     
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

> On successful return of the ajax call, I need to update just the and not the Test1, Test 2 fields. What should I write in the "success" function so that my div gets updated.

I quite dont understand what you want to update, or what you call by "update".

So what do you want to happen? showing those input fields? 
In case of that you can make your div with `display:none` at the beggining, and in success you can set it to `display: block`, or just `$('yourdiv').hide()` on doc load, and `$(.yourdiv').show()` on success.

```
<div id="mydiv">
        <% if @results && @results.any? %>           
            <li>                        
              <% @results.each do |res|%>                
               <span>Field1: </span><span><%= res["field1"]  %></span>
               <span>Field2: </span><span><%= res["field2"] %></span>
              <% end %>
            </li>
        <% end %> 
    </div>
```

From your code, i fail to see your div with values but those on the 2 fields.

IF, and if you mean by updating , just showing the new values ( if you are getting some numbers from your backend every x seconds)
Then what you should do is to set the value from your span ( where those results should be) to that same number. Forcing you to give them a class

```
$('your_class').val(VALUE_TO_BE_SETTED);
```

Feel free to drop a comment to help me understand your question :)

Comment: thank you for your comment! By updating, I do mean getting new numbers from the backend every few seconds. Could you elaborate on $('your_class').val(VALUE_TO_BE_SETTED);

Comment: I updated my code as per your suggestion but it didn't work for me

Comment: you need to point that direct to your span element. and as mention before, ( and is was my mistake) you should use .text() instead. 

if you think about that, the value that a div "can have" is exactly the elements that he has inside.

Comment: Filipe, I ended up using Partials and it worked perfectly! thanks for all your help! Ill post my solution code soon!